# Why doesn't a metre cube of common salt weigh 2170 kg if the density of NaCl lattice is 2170 kg/m^3?

Tags: material-science, density

Why doesn't a metre cube of box containing common salt weigh $2170\ kg$ if the density of NaCl lattice is $2170\ kg/m^3$?

As Mass = Volume x Density then for a unit volume shouldn't Mass= 1 x 2170= 2170 $kg$?
What is the reason behind this?

Comment: Does your common salt contain air?

Comment: @AndersSandberg yeah, just what you would do when someone tells you to pack a metre cube of salt

Answer (score 5):

The sort of salt you use in the kitchen is made up from (approximately) cubic grains, and when you put these into a container then pack randomly with air gaps between the grains.

The packing fraction for randomly packed spheres is around 60%. I don't know what the figure for randomly packed cubes is, but I'd guess it will be similar. So the density of a box of salt grain will be around 60% of the density of a single salt crystal.

Comment: So u mean that remaining 40% space would be occupied by air and this leading to a considerable reduction of weight?

Comment: @Vivekkarunakaran yes